# How to add button in Zxing Scanner page?

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement button in Zxing Scanner page. I tried this link [Add the flashlight button above the Zxing Scanner page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907246/add-the-flashlight-button-above-the-zxing-scanner-page) but it's not working in my code. Here i have attached the java code. Please suggest some good solution.

```
import android.Manifest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class WorkOut extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

Integer response = 0 ;
int currentIndex=0;

private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    Button scanButton = new Button(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    scanButton.setText("Flash Light");
    scanButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.addView(scanButton);

}
private void checkPermissions() {
    try {
        for (int i = currentIndex; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[i]);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
                requestPermission(permissions[i]);
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Activity activity = this;
Context context = this;

String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};


private void requestPermission(String permission) {


    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission},
        101);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 101:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                checkPermissions();
            } else {
                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(response == 1) {
        mScannerView = null;
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        response = 0;

    }

    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();


    mScannerView.stopCamera();

}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d("ani","onrestart");
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Scanned",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: this `but it's not working in my code` means nothing, explain, button not appearing? appearing but not doing anything on click? app crash on activity start? app crash on button click? ... AND SO ON... explain and post any exceptions u have

Comment: Here I am not getting any crash but if I start the activity I saw the button in the seperate page and then its moving to scanning page.I need to implement that button in scanning page

Comment: @RajeshKumar you are getting the button and scanning in separate activities now and need to implement both in single page am i correct?

Comment: yes, its correct.

Comment: How did you fix this issue ?